# VS 2010 shortcut keys not the defaul keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2010

I have installed ReShaper trial version and after that I have set the default shortcut keys which is supported by the Reshaper. Now the trial has expired and it is not working.

My issue is now VS shortcut keys are not enabled. How to solve this?

Eg: If I press ctrl+r ctrl+e to refactor following error is displayed.

**The Key combination (Ctrl+R,Ctrl+E) is bounded to command (ReShaper_EncapsulatedField) which is not currently available.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard. Press 'Reset' button on top of the page.

[image]